# Best approach to display model data in modal pop up in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table that displays information.  When the user clicks on the row, I would like to display the data in a modal pop up. Since the Model already contains my data my initial thought would be to just pass the model to a JavaScript function which would then populate my modal popup but I see that is not possible.

**razr**:

```
foreach (Insurance insurance in Model.Patient.InsuranceCollection)
{
  <tr style="border-bottom:#676767 solid 1px;">
    <td class="table_highlight"><span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="EditInsurance(@insurance)">@insurance.Company</span></td>
    <td>@insurance.IdNumber</td>
    <td>@insurance.Group</td>
    <td>@insurance.PlanType</td>
    <td>@insurance.PaymentRatio</td>
  </tr>
}
```

I know I can pass the id to my function if I do `EditInsurance(@insurance.Id)` and could do an ajax call to the server to pull the data from the database but this seems bad since I already have the data in the model, I just can't seem to figure out the best way to access this model data to display in my pop-up when the user clicks on the row.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reality is that MVC pretty much expects you to pass the ID and then do another dip for the data off that.

That said, you could do this with javascript anyway.. You just need to expose the data as a webservice, then fetch it into a JSON object, and pass it around to modals to your hearts content..

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of stuff you can try various option the easiest way is to use knockout js in which you can pass whole row data in observable function or jquery function and you can do anything with it.